# Change user/group for /var/run/docker.sock ubuntu 19.04

Tags: ubuntu

I'm getting what appears to be a very common error running docker. Doing a 'docker ps' as a normal user, I'll get "Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

A bit of googling provides obvious answers: make the calling user a member of the 'docker' group.  I'm guessing in these cases the assumption is that the linux involved has setup the permissions on the .sock to be root:docker (where the 'docker' group was created as part of installing the docker software).

However on 19.04 the user/group is root/root, and there's no docker group.

I tried using [setfacl](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/use-docker-without-sudo-ubuntu/) to add that user, which worked great! Until  I rebooted. Then, sadness.  Looks like the ACLs were reset.

I'm guessing the ACL is removed because it's a socket and recreated when docker restarts.

How do I persist setfacl for this scenario? Or is there a more '19.04' way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

And here's the answer:

1. A bit of digging inside the snap itself, showed that it *was* looking for a docker group.  That group doesn't exist tho. Humpf.

Sitting within: [dockers own docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/). Just make the group, and assign the user to the group. Done.

Comment: I have found that the surest way to get the /var/run/docker.sock re-created with the group set to 'docker' is to restart (at least with Ubuntu 20). I've tried restarting both snapd and snap.docker.dockerd.service, and only a reboot actually changed it.

Comment: Just tried this on a v20 VM and for me, and it works as long as the docker group is created and user also assigned to that group.  I wonder why this isn't done by the snap install?  oh well.